# KeyError: 124 while running dataframe.loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

While running a code block I found the following error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-1031c1f0832d> in <module>
     19     TBM_data=pd.read_csv(files, header=0, sep='\t')
     20     df_tbm=pd.DataFrame(TBM_data)
---> 21     df_tbmnew=df_tbm.loc[(df_tbm[124]!=0) & (df_tbm[140]!=0) & (df_tbm[141]!=0),[1,124,140,141]]
     22     df_tbmnew['id']=df_tbmnew.index

~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2993             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2994                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2995             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2996             if is_integer(indexer):
   2997                 indexer = [indexer]

~\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:
-> 2899                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2900         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2901         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 124
```

I am trying to read multiple `.txt` files inside a for loop and create subsets from those files using `df.loc` in Python. The code block is:

```
files_path=r"E:\CSM Research\Jilin data work\Pre-collapse segments data\1. Stakes (70817-70800)"

read_files=glob.glob(os.path.join(files_path,"*.txt"))

for files in read_files:
    x=x+1 
    TBM_data=pd.read_csv(files, header=0, sep='\t')
    df_tbm=pd.DataFrame(TBM_data)
    df_tbmnew=df_tbm.loc[(df_tbm[124]!=0) & (df_tbm[140]!=0) & (df_tbm[141]!=0),[1,124,140,141]]
```

Comment: Apparently there is no column labeled 124. How more can we help? That's something you need to figure out...

Comment: I have omitted the header from the text files as the column names are in a different language. So, pandas created automatic numbers as the header of the columns. So, there is a column with a header 124, and I have used the same lines of code outside this loop and that code worked. I am not sure why it is not working inside this for loop.

Comment: header=0 command ensured that the 1st row of the .txt file is omitted and new headings for the columns of numeric values are created. df_tbm[124] indicated the column with heading 124 which is the generated numeric heading of the column. Please don't misunderstand my novice acts as I am completely new in python programming.

Comment: You are doing this for many files. Isn't it possible that some of this files don't have 124 columns?

Comment: Try printing the filename right before `df_tbmnew`.  (the single-filename is `files` in your case; should probably be named `filename`). Then look at the last file printed before the error. Did at least one file get processed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`header=0` means to take first line of csv as column names, if you need `pandas` to auto-numerate column names then you need to pass `header=None`. Also as now you need probably to skip first csv row with foreign column names you should also pass second param `skiprows=1`.